# Solution Explorer different marks

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I tried to figure out what the difference is in the below Solution Exploer image.

[image: Solution Explorer]

The files which are include from the beginning in the project have an red check mark. All files I have added later to the project have an green plus sign. If I go with the mouse over the green plus sign I got "Ausstehender Hinzufügevorgang" which means in english maybe "required add prozess". But if I click with the right mouse button on this file, I can't see any action to add something.
What I have to do, because I got problems with `RUNTIME_CLASS(CStreamAuswertungView2)`. With the one, which has a red check mark it works fine.

Comment: do you use a source control tool?

Comment: I have installed TortoiseGit

Comment: this is a shell extension for explorer. Solution Exploer means VS, so do you also have an extension installed for VS?

Comment: No, I dont have any extension installed.

Comment: with tortoisegit, check for modifications and make sure "show unversioned files" is enabled. now look if StreamAuswertungView2 files are shown as unversioned